# Трудности с выбором базы данных для игры (C#)

Tags: c#, база-данных, разработка-игр

Занимаюсь разработкой небольшой инди-игры на C# с поддержкой игры по сети (под Windows на MS VS, не Xamarin, в дальнейшем планирую написать клиенты под iOS и Android). С точки зрения программирования, ее суть заключается в том, что в памяти сервера крутится несколько десятков тысяч небольших объектов, каждому из которых может принадлежать еще по нескольку предметов или чуть больше. Состояние объектов изменяется каждый игровый тик, это несколько раз в секунду, постоянно создаются новые объекты и предметы, удаляются некоторые старые. Клиенты вне зависимости друг от друга должны получать с каждым тиком часть данных от сервера и, время от времени, посылая запросы непосредственно серверу игры.

Какую базу данных мне стоит выбрать для реализации всего вышеназванного?

Загвоздка в том, что БД должна уметь адекватно работать с несколькими запросами на чтение и запись одновременно (по этой причине я отбросил SQLite), а также быть либо портабельной (примерно как бд у сервера игры Minecraft, он не заставляет устанавливать какое-либо дополнительное ПО, помимо самого себя и Java), либо максимально простой в установке (например, как распространяемый пакет MS Access, только он для таких целей не очень подходит по-моему). По второй причине я отбросил таких монстров как MySQL и подобных: они не позволяют серверу небольшой игры прозрачно выполнять свою работу.

В итоге у меня вообще не осталось никаких вариантов, с которыми я был бы знаком, и я прошу знатоков помочь мне с выбором, так как игр, с похожим на мое описание, существует множество, и все они как-то смогли это реализовать без самописных костылей. С тем, как ее использовать, я разберусь самостоятельно

Comment: "По второй причине я отбросил таких монстров как MySQL и подобных: они не позволяют серверу небольшой игры прозрачно выполнять свою работу." Что? о_О

Comment: Вторая причина надуманная и по ней можно отбросить абсолютно любую СУБД. Но нужна ли вам в этом проекте вообще СУБД, не будет ли достаточно просто структур данных в оперативной памяти? Какого рода связи и в каких количествах на каждую сущность у вас встречаются? Какие гарантии в отношении сохранности/согласованности/целостности данных вам нужны? Так вопрос плавно превращается в "посоветуйте СУБД", который слишком общий для Stack Overflow.

Comment: А зачем SQL, вам же по сути надо все объекты постоянно держать в ОЗУ иначе вам никаких мощностей не хватит, обсчитывать их каждый тик. А для долговременного хранения сбрасываете их на диск и опять же БД вроде как и не нужна вовсе

Comment: Несчастные 10К объектов? Держите всё в памяти и не морочьте нам голову. Для запросов используйте LINQ или держите индексирующие `Dictionary` в памяти, если нужна скорость.

Comment: Ответьте себе на вопрос: зачем Вам в этом проекте нужна БД вообще? Что именно Вы хотите там хранить? Без хотя бы поверхностного описания игры это непонятно. Касательно же решений, MySQL -- ну далеко не монстр, вообще, называть инструмент монстром, потому что он Вам не подходит -- моветон. Если Вы не хотите СУБД, как отдельный сервер, посмотрите в сторону встраиваемых решений, например, Berkeley_DB. Но вопрос "зачем" опять же остается.

Comment: БД нужна там, где нужна персистентность каких-то данных. Например, игровая статистика игроков, аккаунты и связанная с ними информация, необходимая между "партиями". А то, что происходит непосредственно в процессе игры - должно быть в "быстрой" памяти сервера.

Comment: Что ж, всем спасибо за ответы. Погляжу в сторону Berkeley DB. Судя по беглому осмотру, возможно, это как раз то, что мне нужно. Если не подойдет, просто откажусь от БД и буду оптимизировать то, что имею сейчас